# Is there a way in SQL to create a new column that looks at the values in a column that shares multiple rows to determine the value in the new column?

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks similar to what I've attached.

I'm wanting to create a new column that looks at the appt# and any row associated with that appt to see if that appt had the procedure D0330 and marks it yes or no.

So for example B Bradley's appt 8210 did include the procedure D0330. So the new column would be marked yes for both lines 1 & 2 despite line 2 not having that specific procedure in it's row.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOSaV.png)

Comment: You haven't attached the data yet.

Comment: Sorry, it said it included the image but didn't actually. The link should be there now.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data; data is *text*. you can't do this with a calculated column in a table which can only see data in the current row, you would need a query in a *view*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a column of a table that auto-generates a value based on multiple rows, or a subquery, or anything like that. Generated columns can only be based on simple functions that reference columns within the same row.

But you can reference a window of rows in a query, and produce a column of that query result, even though the column is not persisted in the table.

```
SELECT *, MAX(CASE `procedure` WHEN 'D0330' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)
  OVER (PARTITION BY employee) AS `newcolumn` 
FROM mytable;
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
| line | employee  | procedure | apt  | newcolumn |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
|    1 | B Bradley | D0330     | 8210 | Yes       |
|    2 | B Bradley | D1226     | 8210 | Yes       |
|    3 | C Connor  | D1457     | 1130 | No        |
|    4 | D David   | D0330     |  543 | Yes       |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

[Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) require MySQL 8.0.